# Finding a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a homogenous linear differential equation of order two of which $$y=e^x$$ and $$y=x+x^2$$ are two independent solutions. All I can think of is trial and error, how do I go backwards from these two equations to the DE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation is of the form $y''+ay'+by=0$.

Plugging $e^x$, $e^x+ae^x+be^x=0$, i.e. $1+a+b=0$.

Plugging $x+x^2$, $2+a(1+2x)+b(x+x^2)=0$.

Solving for $a$ and $b$,
$$a=\frac{-x^2-x+2}{x^2-x-1}\\b=\frac{2x-1}{x^2-x-1}.$$
Answer:
$$(x^2-x-1)y''+(-x^2-x+2)y'+(2x-1)y=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Put $y_1(x)=\exp(x)$, and $y_2(x)=x+x^2$. One linear differential equation satisfied by $y_1$ and $y_2$ is given by the determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}y(x)& y^{\prime}(x)& y^{\prime\prime}(x) \cr 
y_1(x)& y_1^{\prime}(x)& y_1^{\prime\prime}(x) \cr
y_2(x)& y_2^{\prime}(x)& y_2^{\prime\prime}(x) \cr\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Now you simplify and compute.